# using aggregate to generate report based on multiple categories in r

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a .dbf containing roughly 2.8 million records that contain residential parcel data with a year built category field, a county code field, and a windzone field (for building code restrictions). There are 3  year built categories and 5 wind zones. I need to get the number of parcels for each year built category in each windzone for each county. Basically I have a county (CNTY_ID = 11) with three year built categories (BUILT_CAT = "1" , "2" , "3") each that are also assigned to one of five windspeed categories (WINDSPEED = "100", "110", "120", etc.). I think I need to use the aggregate() function but haven't had any luck. Optimally the generated table would look something like:

```
CNTY_ID = 11
                  BUILT_CAT 
             1        2        3
WINDSPEED
   100       x        x        x
   120       x        x        x
    .
    .
    .
   150       x        x        x

CNTY_ID = 12
                  BUILT_CAT 
             1        2        3
WINDSPEED
   100       x        x        x
   120       x        x        x
    .
    .
    .
   150       x        x        x
```

Is this kind of task possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you essentially need is a way to group your data.

I think `dplyr` is the way to go. You can use `aggregate` too.

**Using `dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)
library(datasets)

temp <- airquality %>% 
  group_by(Month, Day) %>% 
  summarise(TOT = sum(Ozone))

View(temp)
```

This will give you the data in a normalized format where the data is grouped first by `Month` and then by `Day` of the month and then sums the provided variable. `Ozone` in this case. You can also count the values by using `length` in stead.

**Using `aggregate`**

```
temp2 <- aggregate(Ozone ~ Month + Day, data = airquality, sum)
View(temp2)
```

The key difference in the approach is the treatment of `NA`.

Since base R functions do not have a very intuitive treatment of `NAs` and would add the record whenever it encounters it. As a result in group by the `sum` fails for that grouped entity and it is dropped from the resultant.

Here is a [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r) to other group by treatments using `data.table` or `ddply`. You can also achieve this by `plyr` or `tapply`.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more easy to read. I was actually looking at the dplyr package when you posted this!

Comment: @Michael and this doesn't give you counts but the sum of the ozone measurements. That's an entirely different question. If you struggle to read the function `table`, you might want to study R a bit more. How much I love the `dplyr` package, in this case you're using a bazooka to shoot on a mosquito. If you actually needed the counts, that is...

Comment: `table` has been my go to for quick tabulation. It is easy to read and transform, if needed, for folks who interact with R frequently.  As @joris-meys pointed out, the above solution is indeed for `sum` mostly because, I did not have a ready dataset where I could have easily made the point go across and yet be reproducible. Using `length` on any of the grouped by variables will give the count, which I alluded to in my solution.

Comment: Try using my example data and replace sum(Ozone) by length(). Doesn't work. Aggregate also needs an extra variable on the left side. So again this doesn't work for the case described by OP.

Comment: @joris-meys I agree `aggregate` is less flexible and would always need one more variable. `dplyr` and `table` are not bound by the same constraints. Anyways, I just wanted to throw out options for OP to use. I think the important thing here is that he has some insights into various techniques to solve his problem and see flexibility of R in action.

Comment: @JorisMeys Sorry, I should have been more clear. The function wasn't hard to read, but the output wasn't very user friendly. using `dplyr` was much easier to read (output wise) and I did use the `length` function as suggested. I cross checked with original data and it seems to all be accurate. Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're better of using `table`, that's less hassle and more performant. You get an array back, and this one is easily converted to a data frame.

Some test data:

```
n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(
  windspeed = sample(c(110,120,130), n, TRUE),
  built_cat = sample(c(1,2,3),n,TRUE),
  cnty_id = sample(1:20,n,TRUE)
)
```

Constructing the table and converting to a data frame:

```
tbl <- with(df, table(windspeed, built_cat, cnty_id))
as.data.frame(tbl)
```

Note that I use `with` here so I have the variable names automatically as the dimnames of my table. That helps with the conversion.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much exactly what I needed. Now only if I could make it more reader friendly...